# POST and GET methods on the same button

Tags: javascript, c#, http-post, asp.net-core-3.1, http-get

I am currently learning asp.net core 3 and I can't find any help regarding this issue that I have.
I have a form that submits a value with a POST request. But I want the same button to have a GET request that populates another field with a .ajax / xmlhttprequest. But I want the POST method to be executed first and then the GET method. Is it possible to do it? I've tried doing it but I got stuck.

These are the methods inside my controller.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetConvertedAmount()
{
    var rate = await _db.ExchangeRates.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(_tM.Currency)).ToListAsync();         
    _tM.convertToCurrency(rate[0].Rate);
    var amount = _tM.Amount;           
    return Json(amount);           
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CalculateExchangeRatio(int amount_give, string type_to_give)
{
    _tM.Amount = amount_give;
    _tM.Currency = type_to_give;
    return Ok();
}
```

And this is my JS script

```
$('#calculateButton').on("click", function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/trade/getconvertedamount",
            type: "get",
            success: function (amount) {
                console.log(amount);
                alert(amount);
            }
        });

        
    })
```

Comment: _"But I want the POST method to be executed first and then the GET method."_  - Call the GET method in the success method of the POST call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the $.ajax 'done' chaining to complete the entire process:

```
$('#calculateButton').on("click", function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/trade/calculateexchangeratio",
        data: { amount_give: 9.99, type_to_give: 'blahblah' },
        type: "post"
    })
    .done(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/trade/getconvertedamount",
            type: "get"         
        })
        .done(function (amount) { console.log(amount); alert(amount); });
    });
})
```

Comment: If I do this, do I have to remove the POST method and the controller + action from the HTML form tags?

Comment: yes, if you have a <form> element with an action doing the POST piece of it, then you need to remove that as this button click event is doing all the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the similar to the end of the POST method implementation `return RedirectToAction("CalculateExchangeRatio", new { amount_give = 1, type_to_give = 2 });`

So your POST method will be called first and it will call the GET method.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) is the documenttation.

Comment: If I do it this way do I have to change my get method to acomodate the variable?

Comment: @Vlad-MarinCalota, no

Comment: @vivenuna, I've tried doing it your way, even Rex`s way, but it still uses the get method first, no matter what I do. What is this behaviour...

Comment: Because you’re calling the get method from JavaScript,you need to call the post method

Comment: I've deleted the JS and let only html level form submit actions.